# Is there an agreed upon convention for naming ZFC+Large Cardinal Axioms?

Tags: soft-question, set-theory, large-cardinals, convention

Is there an agreed upon convention in general for what to name ZFC+[Large Cardinal Axiom]? Or would one have to state explicitly which axiom was being added?

To explain what I mean, note that anyone who has taken a course in axiomatic set theory will know which axiom is being added when going from ZF to ZFC.

If, for example, one adds the axiom (roughly stated) "for every cardinal there exists a strictly larger inaccessible cardinal" then is there an abbreviation (perhaps ZFC+I?) that any set theorist would recognise? If not for my example, would such abbreviations exist for more notable or more commonly seen axioms?

Comment: Jindra Zapletal ollows the nice convention of talking of $\mathsf{ZFC}+\mathsf{LC}$ to refer to extensions of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ by large cardinals, without bothering to specify the precise extra axioms in each case (for instance, "it is a theorem of $\mathsf{ZFC}+\mathsf{LC}$ that every set of reals in $L(\mathbb R)$ is determinded, and therefore ..."). It is useful when one is interested in working with specific consequences of large cardinals (typically, previously established in the literature) rather than in the precise calibration of these consequences in terms of consistency strength.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that whenever I saw anyone using anything stronger than $\sf ZFC$, the axioms were defined explicitly. Except, perhaps, things like $I0,I1,I2,I3$ which are essentially the conventional names for these statements.

Most of the time you write either something like "We abbreviate by $\sf IC$ the statement "There exists an inaccessible cardinal", and in the following section we will work with the theory $\sf ZFC+IC$"; or you just write the axiom explicitly each time along the lines of "Assume that $\kappa$ is a measurable limit of Woodin cardinals, then ..."

Comment: That exactly answers my question, thank you :)

Comment: Which axioms do I0, I1, etc. represent, by the way? (Edit: Never mind, it was only a quick search away.)